# Hive Streaming with python script

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am working in Hive streaming with python scripts. I need some results of one hive streaming query rather than the output saved into a table for the execution of next query. How can i save such details in Hadoop ?
I have been tested by creating a file in distributed cache but that file becomes empty while running the second query.